# Python3.8 venv without activate script

Tags: bash, scripts, python, python3, virtualenv

When I try to create a virtual environment, the created folder does not have the venv/bin/activate script.
I tried to install and reinstall venv using `sudo apt install python3-venv`, but it always comes broken (without the script).
I also tried to use virtualenv (tried to install it using both `sudo apt install python3-virtualenv` and `pip install virtualenv`), but it also doesn't create the script.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26215790/venv-doesnt-create-activate-script-python3/26314477) help you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For some reason I tried to reinstall it again some times and now it worked.
I think i forgot to purge the package the last time and it tried to reinstall the package that was already downloaded.
So I ran `sudo apt purge python3-venv` and `sudo apt install python3-venv` and it worked.

Comment: Ran into the same thing here... the first installation of `python3-venv` created an env folder without the `activate` script so I purged and reinstalled as described here and it started working.